# How to Parse uri in ruby without Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

My Code,

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = 'http://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=tycho'
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
JSON.parse(response)
puts(response)
```

This works as long as it is http but the instance it is https it fails with Authentication error.

Actual Error:
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (error number 1) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

In Curl I can use insecure mode which helps get the results as shown in the example below:

```
curl --insecure -X GET -H "content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{}' "http://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=tycho"
```

What would the equivalent method be for "net/http" method where i could add insecure or validation=false.

I will be using the output to append a recipe in CHEF.

NOTE: The correct URI will be different and not the one mentioned in the above link

Any leads is greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Anish

Comment: Set `verify_mode` option to `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` like `Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)`.

Comment: Also you might rely on system `curl`: `response = %x[curl --insecure ....]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, Is there a sample script that you could provide, Having a hard time debugging the solution you provided. Please

Comment: Documentation page on [`Net::HTTP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS) is full of these examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off certificate verification, try this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=tycho'
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl     = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

response = http.request_get(uri.path).body
JSON.parse(response)
puts(response)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 8: from sara.rb:7:in `<main>'
 1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (error number 1) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Comment: Note that you have to set `use_ssl` AND `verify_mode`. Both need to be set.

Comment: Works like a charm, Since i only wanted the json output changed the last line

response = http.request_get(uri).body